# Удалить используемый docker volume

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

Есть вот такой конфиг `docker-compose`

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_EXPOSE_PORT}:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - .env
  app:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --workers 4 --log-config ../uvicorn_log.ini asgi:application
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/media
      - ${LOGGING_DIR}:/home/app/logs
    expose:
      - "8000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "${NGINX_LISTEN_PORT}:80"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/media
      - ${LOGGING_DIR}/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    depends_on:
      - app

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Контейнеры `app` и `nginx` используют один и тот же volume со статическими файлами. У меня есть скрипт, работающий с вебхуками гитхаба, который пересобирает контейнеры после обновления репозитория.

Выглядит это примерно так:

```bash
git pull origin
docker-compose down
docker volume rm static_volume
docker-compose build --no-cache
docker-compose up -d
```

Я хочу немного изменить этот механизм, оставив работать `nginx`, так как его пересобирать не нужно, и, пока пересобирается `app`, `nginx` будет отдавать статическую страницу с оповещением о тех. обслуживании.

Вся проблема в `static_volume`, мне необходимо пересоздавать её, чтобы в контейнер подтягивалась новая статика из репозитория. В ином случае он будет использовать старый volume со старой статикой.

Но если я оставляю работать `nginx`, то и volume я не могу удалить, так как его использует контейнер. Как поступить в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, я немного неправильно подошел к моменту сборки статики. Сборку статики я запускал на стадии сборки контейнера, и после его создания статика перезаписывалась старым volume с хоста. Перенес команду сбора статики в entrypoint скрипт, и теперь удалять `static_volume` не нужно.